# get a list of unique date from the stream grouping

Tags: java, java-stream

I have data:

```
id|date
1 |12-12-2021
2 |12-12-2021
3 |13-12-2021
```

Want to get a list of dates: ["12-12-2021", "13-12-2021"]

Using stream, I can get a map:

```
txs.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(g -> g.getDate()));
```

I would like to convert to list in from the stream above.

Comment: What if you use `map` to get the date, make the stream `distinct`, and `collect` it to a list? Or map it to a date stream and collect it to set by using a good set factory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`groupingBy` is not the best choice in your case. Use `distinct` instead. It will automatically filter out all duplicates.

```
txs.stream().map(g -> g.getDate()).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: IMHO a better solution because the iteration order might be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the data in `Map<Integer,LocalDate>` the you can use `values()` and collect to `Set` to eliminate duplicates

```
Set<LocalDate> dates = txs.values().stream().collect(Collectors.toSet())
```

or using `HashSet`

```
new HashSet<>(txs.values());
```

Comment: If you have the data in `Map<Integer, LocalDate>` you could just use `new HashSet<>(txs.values())`. No need for streams.